# LocationManager getLastKnownLocation with passive provider

Tags: java, android, android-source

I have a **legacy app** which, in a certain activity, requires user location. This location doesn't need to be precise, so my criteria is

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

which retuns `network` provider in general. At some point, I call `getLastKnownLocation(provider)` with this provider.

Everything works fine. When I switch to settings and turn off location and switch back to app, my `provider` becomes `"passive"`.

So I just need the last location since precision is not that important, I continue and call `getLastKnownLocation(provider)`.

On API 19 -> `getLastKnownLocation("passive")` returns a `Location` object. This object's provider is `network`, also lat / long values confirms this is the location it most recently acquired.

On API 21+ -> `getLastKnownLocation("passive")` returns null.

I'm %100 positive I have a location before switching and turning off location service. I've gone through documentation / diff of `LocationManager` but couldn't find any info regarding this.

Is there any info / doc about why would it be behaving this way on 21+ ?